# Eigen: how to convert the result of "greater than" (on ArrayXf) to Eigen vector

Tags: c++, eigen

Consider the following code:

```
Eigen::VectorXf classify()
{
   Eigen::VectorXf probability(4);
   probability << 0.9, 0.8, -0.1, 0.2;

   auto y_pred = probability.array() > 0.8; //what is the type of y_pred?
   //y_pred looks like [1 0 0 0]

   // how to return y_pred as a VectorXf? 
   // I'm trying this, but it is not working:
   return static_cast<Eigen::VectorXf>(y_pred); //doesn't work
}

int main() 
{
   classify();
}
```

2 questions:

- (for my understanding) What is the type of `y_pred`? I was thinking it is an `ArrayXf` but it seems not to be the case
- (the question this post is about) how can I convert `y_pred` to an Eigen vector (`VectorXf` or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y_pred` is an abstract expression. It's type is something like (simplified for readability):

```
CWiseBinaryOp<greater<float>,ArrayWrapper<VectorXf>,CwiseNullaryOp<Constant<float>,ArrayXf>>
```

It inherits `ArrayBase` and its `Scalar` type is `bool`.

If you want a `VectorXf`, then cast the bools to floats:

```
VectorXf foo = y_pred.cast<float>();
```

The cast from *array* to *matrix* is implicit in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html), you will notice that `Eigen::VectorXf` is actually a `typedef` for `Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>`.

## Type of `y_pred`

The `Eigen::Matrix` class derives from the [`Eigen::MatrixBase`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html) template class, which is where the `array()` member function comes from. This method returns a wrapper object, which can basically be considered as an [`Eigen::Array`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Array.html). Applying the comparison operator to the result of `array()` yields an `Eigen::Array` of `bool`.

## Converting to a vector-like type

The documentation has a [section](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) dedicated to the use of the `Eigen::Array` class. One subsection, namely *Converting between array and matrix expressions*, is of particular interest in the context of your question.  There, one can read that an `Eigen::Array` may be converted to an `Eigen::Matrix` by using the [`matrix()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#af01e9ea8087e390af8af453bbe4c276c) method.

Using the above observations, you should be able to convert `y_pred` to some kind of vector by returning `y_pred.matrix()` instead of `static_cast<Eigen::VectorXf>(y_pred)`. The return type will likely be something like `Eigen::Matrix<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>`.

Due to the fact that matrices of `bool` are less common in linear algebra operations, there are no `typedef`s associated to them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
The answers to the first question is now clear to me. 
Regarding the second question `return y_pred.matrix()` doesn't work.
The only way I see to go around this is defining a new type 
`typedef Eigen::Array<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> ArrayXb` and use it as the return type instead of `Eigen::VectorXf`. Why does Eigen have no array or vector of bool?

Comment: Eigen does include support for arrays and vectors of `bool`. However, there are no `typedef`s for those types, as they are less commonly used. I will update my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score -1):

No,progress will operate the right expression so auto a=3>2 it will return bool:1 or 0.(if the right expression is true the value of left is 1)
so, the type of y_pred is bool.

Comment: No, y_pred is a column vector (or maybe a 4by1 array), I can verify it by printing it with std::cout. it give me [1 0 0 0]